# Any license cost when Google container optimized OS in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are using the `Google container optimized OS` for our processing framework. I wanted to calculate the cost for a month if I use VM for 5 per hour daily.

I did not understand which operating system I need to select from the dropdown.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are no license costs attached with the gcp container optimized os, so the first line would be correct (it's comparable to CoreOS).

Comment: means I have to select the free option from the drop-down to calcualte my cost??